# multiple tableview controller in one viewcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to add manually or pragmatically two more tableview in one view controller vertically like below BBC screen.

[image]

Comment: There are **many** ways to accomplish this. At the top of my head, I can tell (1) Use single table view, and reload each time the 'tab' is changed. Draw cell content depending upon the current selected tab. (2) Use multiple table views and show one at any point of time keeping others hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not multiple tableview in same screen but you may use sectioned tableview. There are methods to customize appearance of sectioned tableview and can create same as above tableview.

You may get good tutorial on this. Some examples are [example 1](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/) and [example 2](http://shrikar.com/blog/2014/12/27/xcode-6-tutorial-grouped-uitableview/)